# H.323, How to make a simple ring without media. This script was following Q.931 setup but still not working

Tags: java, linux, protocols, wireshark, h.323

Can anyone please help me to solve this? When i send this request i have seen in wireshark that packets are going to SJPhone in 1720 tcp port. But still SJPhone does not ring. I want to make it ring (no matter for media).

I would really appreciate your support. I must be missing the message protocol details to implement this. Please show me some positive pointers.

FYI: i have used this trace: http://www.vconsole.com/usermanuals/sample_isdn_trace.pdf

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException 
    { 
        /* Step 1: simulate the Q.931 packets exchange */
        byte st[]=new byte[256];
        st[0]=0x08;    // protocol discriminator
        st[1]=0x02;    // length (bytes) of call reference
        st[2]=0x02;    // call reference (1-15 bytes)        
        // message type
        st[3]=0x05;            
        // information Elements
        st[4]=0x6C;     // calling party number
            st[5]=0;    // unknown
            st[6]=0;    // unknown
            st[7]=1;    // "1"
        // information elements
        st[8]=0x70;     // called party number 
            st[9]=0;    // unknown
            st[10]=0;   // unknown  
            st[11]=5;   // "5"
        System.out.println(st);

        /* Step 2: by-pass it for testing with tcpdump */
        Socket clientSocket           = new Socket("localhost", 1720);
        DataInputStream input         = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());          
        DataOutputStream outToServer  = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer   = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        outToServer.write(st);
        String get;
        get = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + get);
        clientSocket.close();        
    }
}
```

--More info:
-When SJPhone to SJPhone communicate i see this logs:

```
0000  00 00 03 04 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00   ................
0010  45 00 00 3c 88 6c 40 00 40 06 b4 4d 7f 00 00 01   E..<.l@.@..M....
0020  7f 00 00 01 b4 a8 06 b8 56 f6 c4 b3 00 00 00 00   ........V.......
0030  a0 02 80 18 fe 30 00 00 02 04 40 0c 04 02 08 0a   .....0....@.....
0040  02 a1 4c df 00 00 00 00 01 03 03 06               ..L.........
```

-When this test.java communicate to SJPhone i see this logs:

```
0000  00 00 03 04 00 06 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00   ........ ........
0010  45 00 00 3c 1f ba 40 00  40 06 1d 00 7f 00 00 01   E..<..@. @.......
0020  7f 00 00 01 d6 ca 06 b8  8c e7 41 15 00 00 00 00   ........ ..A.....
0030  a0 02 80 18 fe 30 00 00  02 04 40 0c 04 02 08 0a   .....0.. ..@.....
0040  02 a6 5e af 00 00 00 00  01 03 03 06               ..^..... ....
```

Note:

Friendly dump can be done using this command, to see realtime + save what you have seen: tcpdump -XX -s 0 -i lo | tee /tmp/log.log

Comment: Yes, indeed. Nice project. SJPhone is not available for Mac Intel processors... Only for PowerPC. So, this means I have to use Linux or Windows. If you are still interested, I will try to work on it this weekend, or maybe some of these evenings. Let me know something.

Comment: The given data, are these part of the TCP Protocol headers? I'm not able to find the sequence `08 02 02`, which you hardcoded in Java.

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux: I would say in my little brain its very complicated. 1. SJPhone works using Wine in my Linux. And with Windows XP (using virtual box/qemu). 2. Protocol headers you can see in the list found here RX: http://www.vconsole.com/usermanuals/sample_isdn_trace.pdf  , all other documents are very complicated, i just wanted to walk with coding. I wrote a SIP registration application too. But in H.323 its completely a new way of doing, never did or expected such complex it can be.

Comment: If we can simulate the same packets in that PDF, it will work, we can send call initiate signal to straight SJPhone, and that will start getting ring tone that someone is calling. (That was the same success with SIP protocol that i did, that was easier but this one, cant find any head nor tail). So.. you are the Genius.

Comment: Can you post the complete whireshark package? Or send me the capture. I'm talking about the SJPhone to SJPhone capture. Email is: martijn*dot*courteaux*at*skynet*dot*be

Comment: Emailed + You can see the files from here https://gist.github.com/1211774  (and this is the wireshark raw file you can save it as name sjphone.to.sjphone and load in wireshark too e.g: https://raw.github.com/gist/1211782/2115cceecaca7d69b99db91f62cc2da11260fc6a/gistfile1.txt )

Comment: This is a successful capture with raw packets on it: https://gist.github.com/1211863

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the question was only to send a ring, without an actual call.

Here is some code that does the job. It was a lot of fun to see when it started working:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 *
 * @author martijncourteaux
 */
public class SJPhoneRinger
{

    private static String setupOpenLogicChannel = "03|00|02|32|08|02|10|00|05|04|03|88|c0|a5|28|07|75|6e|6b|6e|6f|77|6e|6c|05|81|32|30|30|35|7e|02|11|05|20|88|06|00|08|91|4a|00|04|22|c0|00|00|00|00|0f|53|4a|20|4c|61|62|73|ae|20|53|4a|70|68|6f|6e|65|08|31|2e|36|30|2e|32|39|39|61|00|7f|00|00|01|06|b8|00|c4|a1|56|3c|d2|1d|b2|11|a8|ed|b7|8a|c2|c1|98|8f|00|c1|1d|80|04|11|00|f6|a1|56|3c|d2|1d|b2|11|a8|ed|b7|8a|c2|c1|98|8f|81|3a|0a|21|40|00|00|06|04|01|00|4e|0c|03|00|20|00|80|12|1e|00|01|00|7f|00|00|01|c0|04|00|7f|00|00|01|c0|05|00|2b|40|00|00|06|04|01|00|4c|10|00|00|00|00|09|69|4c|42|43|2d|31|33|6b|33|80|12|1e|40|01|00|7f|00|00|01|c0|04|00|7f|00|00|01|c0|05|04|2b|40|00|00|06|04|01|00|4c|10|00|00|00|00|09|69|4c|42|43|2d|31|35|6b|32|80|12|1e|40|01|00|7f|00|00|01|c0|04|00|7f|00|00|01|c0|05|08|1e|40|00|00|06|04|01|00|4c|20|13|80|12|1e|00|01|00|7f|00|00|01|c0|04|00|7f|00|00|01|c0|05|00|1e|40|00|00|06|04|01|00|4c|60|13|80|12|1e|00|01|00|7f|00|00|01|c0|04|00|7f|00|00|01|c0|05|00|16|00|00|0d|0e|0c|03|00|20|00|80|0b|06|00|01|00|7f|00|00|01|c0|05|00|20|00|00|0e|0c|10|00|00|00|00|09|69|4c|42|43|2d|31|33|6b|33|80|0b|06|40|01|00|7f|00|00|01|c0|05|04|20|00|00|0f|0c|10|00|00|00|00|09|69|4c|42|43|2d|31|35|6b|32|80|0b|06|40|01|00|7f|00|00|01|c0|05|08|13|00|00|10|0c|20|13|80|0b|06|00|01|00|7f|00|00|01|c0|05|00|13|00|00|11|0c|60|13|80|0b|06|00|01|00|7f|00|00|01|c0|05|00|01|00|01|00|01|00|01|00|6e|02|64|02|70|01|06|00|08|81|75|00|08|80|0d|00|00|3c|00|01|00|00|01|00|00|01|00|00|04|80|00|00|24|18|03|00|20|00|80|00|01|20|20|00|00|00|00|09|69|4c|42|43|2d|31|33|6b|33|80|00|02|20|20|00|00|00|00|09|69|4c|42|43|2d|31|35|6b|32|80|00|03|20|40|13|80|00|04|20|c0|13|00|80|06|00|04|00|00|00|01|00|02|00|03|00|04|07|01|00|32|80|d8|50|5f|02|80|01|80";
    private static String alertingTSCA = "03|00|00|d8|08|02|90|00|01|28|07|75|6e|6b|6e|6f|77|6e|7e|00|c3|05|23|c0|06|00|08|91|4a|00|04|22|c0|00|00|00|00|0f|53|4a|20|4c|61|62|73|ae|20|53|4a|70|68|6f|6e|65|08|31|2e|36|30|2e|32|38|39|61|00|5e|e0|cc|44|98|ff|0d|0c|11|00|f6|a1|56|3c|d2|1d|b2|11|a8|ed|b7|8a|c2|c1|98|8f|01|00|01|00|04|c0|01|80|74|04|03|21|80|01|64|02|70|01|06|00|08|81|75|00|08|80|0d|00|00|3c|00|01|00|00|01|00|00|01|00|00|04|80|00|00|24|18|03|00|20|00|80|00|01|20|20|00|00|00|00|09|69|4c|42|43|2d|31|33|6b|33|80|00|02|20|20|00|00|00|00|09|69|4c|42|43|2d|31|35|6b|32|80|00|03|20|40|13|80|00|04|20|c0|13|00|80|06|00|04|00|00|00|01|00|02|00|03|00|04|06|01|00|32|40|1b|33|02|20|80";
    private static String facilityTSCA = "03|00|00|62|08|02|10|00|62|1c|00|28|07|75|6e|6b|6e|6f|77|6e|7e|00|4b|05|26|90|06|00|08|91|4a|00|04|c4|a1|56|3c|d2|1d|b2|11|a8|ed|b7|8a|c2|c1|98|8f|86|01|00|13|05|80|11|00|f6|a1|56|3c|d2|1d|b2|11|a8|ed|b7|8a|c2|c1|98|8f|07|00|5e|e0|cc|44|ab|62|01|00|01|00|04|c0|01|80|08|02|03|21|80|01|02|20|a0";
    private static String connectOpenLogicChannel = "03|00|00|b6|08|02|90|00|07|28|07|75|6e|6b|6e|6f|77|6e|7e|00|a1|05|22|c0|06|00|08|91|4a|00|04|00|5e|e0|cc|44|98|ff|22|c0|00|00|00|00|0f|53|4a|20|4c|61|62|73|ae|20|53|4a|70|68|6f|6e|65|08|31|2e|36|30|2e|32|38|39|61|00|c4|a1|56|3c|d2|1d|b2|11|a8|ed|b7|8a|c2|c1|98|8f|0d|1c|11|00|f6|a1|56|3c|d2|1d|b2|11|a8|ed|b7|8a|c2|c1|98|8f|41|02|21|40|00|03|06|04|01|00|4e|0c|03|00|20|00|80|12|1e|00|01|00|7f|00|00|01|c0|04|00|5e|e0|cc|44|c0|07|00|1d|00|00|0d|0e|0c|03|00|20|00|80|12|1e|00|01|00|5e|e0|cc|44|c0|06|00|5e|e0|cc|44|c0|07|00|01|00|01|00|02|80|01|80";

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1720);
        System.out.println("Connected to SJPhone!");

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        sendBytes(dos, setupOpenLogicChannel);

        /* Following three packages were not needed. It worked without them.
         * Of course, because it is only a sample ring request, SJPhone will tell you
         * That the call is corrupted */
//        sendBytes(dos, alertingTSCA);
//        sendBytes(dos, facilityTSCA);
//        sendBytes(dos, connectOpenLogicChannel);

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(10000); // Let it ring for ten seconds.
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

    public static void sendBytes(OutputStream os, String bytes) throws IOException
    {
        String byteArrayStr[] = bytes.split("\\|");
        byte bytesArray[] = new byte[byteArrayStr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < byteArrayStr.length; ++i)
        {
            bytesArray[i] = (byte) (Integer.parseInt(byteArrayStr[i],16));
        }
        os.write(bytesArray);
        os.flush();
    }


}
```

Comment: Oh my god oh my god. You are Scientist/Genius, you just took less then 1 minute? Oh my god, i am amazing with your talent. God i have never seen like this, really. Oh my god it was like "bang" its done. Excellent, its so much to learn from you. Many many thanks. I really appreciate that you are genius.

Comment: You are welcome! Now, I'm going to write my f*cking text for Dutch. I'm still at secondary school... :( I'm looking forward to the times after this. :D