# java how to send binary packet data

Tags: java, sockets

I created serversocket in java and i am unable to send binary packet response to Teltonica fmxxxx device. can any one help me...

and this is my code

```
DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
byte[] b={0x01};
outToClient.write(b,0,len);
outToClient.write('\n');
outToClient.flush();
```

Comment: Hope it will help :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106762/how-to-send-such-complicated-hex-binary-protocol-data-accurately-using-java-byt

Comment: From my experience years back .. Teltonica fm are using serial com and not socket . no ?

Comment: Binary data isn't line-terminated. There is something wrong with what you're sending. But 'unable to send' isn't a problem description.