# H.323 Request Java

Tags: java, request, call, send, h.323

I need to send a call using h.323 protocol in java, I do not need audio, just the call connects. for that I am using an IP gateway, but I need to send the request mode and ready, like I can do?

Comment: try using this example, but not how to adapt it for what I need [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098801/h-323-how-to-make-a-simple-ring-without-media-this-script-was-following-q-931)

Comment: The example you link to doesn't encode any H.323 signaling messages, but sends binary copies of messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a there is a publically available library that implements H.323 signaling in Java, but there are 2 libraries with a C interface that you might be able to use from Java:

[OPAL](http://www.opalvoip.org/) is OpenSource, support H.323 and has a C wrapper.

The commercial Radvision H.323 SDK also has a C interface.

If anyone knows more options, please comment, but I think thats it (asside from storing binary copies of the ASN.1 messages and trying to patch them on the fly).